# What would have been the process of arresting someone in the Middle Ages?

Tags: middle-ages, crime

In the High Middle Ages (France, specifically), if someone was suspected of having committed a crime, would that person have been arrested? Would that person have been jailed somewhere until their trial? I hear a lot about the trial system and the punishments, and I know that many towns had bailiffs, but what would the process have been *before* the trial? What if the suspect wanted to prove one's innocence?

Specifically, I'm asking about a commoner - a traveling merchant, perhaps - who was accused of murder in a smaller village controlled by a noble.

Comment: Please let us know where you have looked already so that others don't duplicate your research efforts. Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK, Depends on your birth (common, noble), your crime (high justice, low justice) and your location. the area we know as "France" was several different political entities, and even within "France", the outcome could be different if you were in a city, or in a Royal controlled area (unlikely) or one controlled by another noble.

Comment: @LarsBosteen: no real "research", per se - just dozens of documentaries, heaps of YouTube videos, The Time Traveller's Guide to Medieval England, and Morris Bishop's The Middle Ages. Any additional info would be awesome

Comment: @MCW: that makes sense. I'm thinking a commoner - a traveling merchant, perhaps? -  for murder, in a smaller village controlled by a noble.

Comment: Let's be clear just what can be meant by [France, in the year 1180](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/France_in_the_Middle_Ages#/media/File:Territorial_Conquests_of_Philip_II_of_France.png) for instance. It's not much more than modern Provence, Cotes du Rhone, Picardy, and Isle de France at that date. The English rule considerably more, and Burgundy another substantial chunk.

Comment: This is not a time or place I've studied enough to provide an answer, but to my understanding the critical word in your question is "travelling".  People have rights to the extent that they have a social network; people who lack a places in the local social fabric have only the rights that the local social fabric chooses to grant.  "victim blaming" would be the norm, not the exception.  Premodern culture is largely xenophobic, and based on a negative sum expectation.  Anyone from out of town will not have local interests at heart, so they must be dangerous.  No-one will complain about arrest.